# cordova.plugins no contiene los plugins instalados

Tags: javascript, cordova, phonegap

Estoy creando una app con cordova. No tengo problemas en utilizar la mayoria de plugins, solo aquellos a los que tengo que acceder a través del objecto `cordova.plugins`.

Por ejemplo, cuando instalo [cordova.plugins.diagnostics](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova.plugins.diagnostic) o [cordova-plugin-request-location-accuracy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-request-location-accuracy), al intentar acceder a ellos mediante el objecto `cordova.plugins.locationAccuracy` me devuelve `undefined`, es decir, que no existe la propiedad locationAccuracy. Lo mismo sucede con diagnostics, y cualquier otro plugin al que haya que acceder de esta manera.

He probado a borrar y reinstalar las plataformas y los plugins y nada. Llevo varios dias con este problema y no encuentro ninguna solución.

Os dejo el repositorio de la app, y el xml:

https://github.com/wanderdust/geoapp

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.amigos.geoapp" version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>HelloCordova</name>
    <description>
        A sample Apache Cordova application that responds to the deviceready event.
    </description>
    <author email="dev@cordova.apache.org" href="http://cordova.io">
        Apache Cordova Team
    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <access origin="http://192.168.0.30:3000/" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
    </platform>
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.contacts" />
    <engine name="android" spec="^7.0.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="^1.3.3" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-geolocation" spec="^4.0.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-camera" spec="^4.0.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-dialogs" spec="^2.0.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-console" spec="^1.1.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova.plugins.diagnostic" spec="^3.9.2" />
</widget>
```

**[EDIT]**

Estoy usando mi movil (samsung galaxy s5) para probar la app, y estoy utilizando la consola de phonegap.

Este es el código (simplificado) que utilizo para comprobar los plugins con diagnostics ya instalado:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", foo, false);

function foo () {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(cordova.plugins));
    console.log(typeof(cordova.plugins.diagnostics) === 'undefined');
}
```

el resultado:

```
{"screenorientation":{},"barcodeScanner":{"Encode":{"TEXT_TYPE":"TEXT_TYPE","EMAIL_TYPE":"EMAIL_TYPE","PHONE_TYPE":"PHONE_TYPE","SMS_TYPE":"SMS_TYPE"},"format":{"all_1D":61918,"aztec":1,"codabar":2,"code_128":16,"code_39":4,"code_93":8,"data_MATRIX":32,"ean_13":128,"ean_8":64,"itf":256,"maxicode":512,"msi":131072,"pdf_417":1024,"plessey":262144,"qr_CODE":2048,"rss_14":4096,"rss_EXPANDED":8192,"upc_A":16384,"upc_E":32768,"upc_EAN_EXTENSION":65536}}}

true
```

Esta es la lista de plugins en el momento que ejecuté este ejemplo:

- cordova-plugin-camera 4.0.1 "Camera"
- cordova-plugin-dialogs 2.0.1 "Notification"
- cordova-plugin-geolocation 4.0.1 "Geolocation"
- cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.3 "Whitelist"
- cordova.plugins.diagnostic 3.9.2 "Diagnostic"

Comment: Parece que `cordova-plugin-request-location-accuracy` no aparece en la lista de plugins en el archivo de configuración... aunque tampoco está el de barcodeScanner que sí te aparece abajo, con lo cual no sé si es importante o no realmente.

Comment: Hola Alvaro perdona, pero es que he estado tocando reinstalando e instalando. En el ejemplo solo tengo diagnostics instalado. Y en el repositorio no tengo ninguno de los 2 ya que al no funcionarme no he hecho ningún commit. barcodeScanner no lo he instalado nunca... Puede ser que se me estén instalando otros plugins? Hay alguna forma de modificar ese objeto de forma manual?

Comment: No te preocupes. Sólo estoy buscando posibles razones por las que fallase. Veo que estás llamando al plugin cuando el dispositivo ya está listo (`deviceready`) que sería la causa más común. Otra posible causa sería si no tuvieras instalada la biblioteca de Google Play Services, ¿la tienes instalada? También podría ocurrir si la app no tiene permisos de localización en el dispositivo (aunque esto parece que es más iOS que android)

Comment: Una vez intenté instalar la biblioteca de Google Play para ver si se solucionaba el problema, pero es posible que hiciera algo mal al instalarla, ya que lo hice a traves de npm y no sé si se instaló en el lugar correcto. Voy a volver a intentarlo a ver si funciona. Me puedes decir cual instalo y como y así asegurarme? Gracias!

Comment: abre el Android SDK Manager, y en la lista de paquetes instalados, ve a la sección de "Extras" y asegúrate de que tienes instalado y actualizado el paquete "Google Repository"

Comment: Bueno estoy utilizando mi móvil en lugar de un emulador avd. lo que he hecho ha sido  `cordova plugin add com.google.playservices` y añadirlo como plugin, y no ha funcionado... Estoy intentando probarlo en un emulador de android a ver si funciona, por si fuera un problema de mi móvil.